# Scrapy - Can't call scraper from a script in parent folder to scrapy project

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've got a bit of a strange one that I can't get my head around here:

I've setup a webscraper using Scrapy and it performs the scrape fine when I run the following file from the cli (`$ python journal_scraper.py`):

*journal_scraper.py:*

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

def checkForUpdates():
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    process.crawl('journal')
    process.crawl('article')
    process.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkForUpdates()
```

The `process` is able to find the two spiders `journal` and `article` without a problem.

Now, I'd like to call this scrape as one of many steps within an application that I'm developing so **from the parent folder to the Scrapy project** I import `journal_scraper.py` into my `main.py` file and try run the `checkForUpdates()` function:

*main.py:*

```
from scripts.journal_scraper import checkForUpdates
checkForUpdates()
```

and I get the following:

```
2016-01-10 20:30:56 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-01-10 20:30:56 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-01-10 20:30:56 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    checkForUpdates()
  File "/Users/oldo/Python/projects/AMS-Journal-Scraping/AMS_Journals/scripts/journal_scraper.py", line 8, in checkForUpdates
    process.crawl('journal')
  File "/Users/oldo/Python/virtual-environments/AMS-Journal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 150, in crawl
    crawler = self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/Users/oldo/Python/virtual-environments/AMS-Journal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 165, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/Users/oldo/Python/virtual-environments/AMS-Journal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 40, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: journal'
```

I've also tried changing `main.py` to:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('python ./scripts/scraper.py', shell=True)
```

Which yields the same error.

I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with the fact that I am calling this function form the parent folder because if I make a little test script in the same folder as `journal_scraper.py` that does the same thing as `main.py` the scraper runs as expected.

Is there some sort of restriction on calling scrapers from a script external to the Scrapy project?

Please ask for further details if my situation is not clear.

Comment: have you tried putting an empty file entitled___init___.py in the folder you want to import from (two underscored each side of the init)? Often this can be the reason imports fail with custom function imports

Comment: @Chris Yeah, there is an `__init__.py` file. Importing and calling the `checkForUpdates()` function is not the problem, it is something to do with Scrapy not being able to find the spiders.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is very late and if you still looking for the solution, Try importing the class of your spider:

```
from parent1.parent1.spiders.spider_file_name import spider_class_name
```